# $f(x+h)$ not equal to $f(x) +f(h)$???

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I'm taking College Algebra at a local community college, and I just wasn't able to follow how my professor came to these conclusions. (3 separate times.)

$$\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h},$$ 
$$f(x) = 2x-7.$$

My professor is got $\frac{2(x+h)-7-2x+7}{h}$.
The difference quotient states though that $(f-g)(x) = f(x)-g(x)$.
If I followed the difference quotient rule I would get, $\frac{f(x)+f(h)-f(x)}{h}$, which would be $\frac{f(h)}{h}$.

So my question is why is she substituting $x+h$ in for $x$ in one $f(x)$ and not another $f(x)$? I thought perhaps that $x+h$ was the input, but then that would change all the $f(x)$'s, not just one. Any ideas?

Comment: The input of one of the $f$'s is $x+h$, while for the other it is $x$.

Comment: It is true that $(f-g)(x)=f(x)-g(x)$. But not $f(x)-f(y)=f(x-y)$.

Answer (score 2):

The difference quotient is

$$\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}$$

The input for the first term in the numerator is $x + h$.  The input for the second term in the numerator is $x$.

If the function is $f(x) = 2x - 7$, then $f(u) = 2u - 7$.  Replacing $u$ by $x + h$ yields $f(x + h) = 2(x + h) - 7$.  Therefore, the difference quotient is

\begin{align*}
\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h} & = \frac{2(x + h) - 7 - (2x - 7)}{h}\\
                          & = \frac{2x + 2h - 7 - 2x + 7}{h}\\
                          & = \frac{2h}{h}\\
                          & = 2
\end{align*}

which is equal to the slope of the line $y = 2x - 7$ that represents the graph of the function $f(x) = 2x - 7$.  In calculus, the difference quotient is used in the definition of the derivative, which tells you the slope of the tangent line to a curve.

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes perfect sense now.